# What is the easiest way to get the S rank mansion in Luigi Mansion original?

Tags: luigis-mansion

I got the A rank, but I can't figure out how to get enough money and gems.
Can anyone maybe tell me about the secret rooms or hidden gems that are available?
Is there a guide to grinding money and gems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I've seen in online playthroughs, there is no "griding" for money.
Theres a fixed amount of money in the game and you can permanently lost some.

I would advise you to follow [this guide](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/gamecube/516494-luigis-mansion/faqs/55392) or one of the numerous videos available on YouTube.

Also, remember that the maximum score is different between PAL and NTSC versions of the game.

Answer (score 0):

There is no S rank in the original version of Luigi's Mansion. That was added in the 3DS rerelease.

If you are playing the 3DS version, there are guides like [this one](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/3ds/234533-luigis-mansion/faqs/55392) available online detailing where all the treasure is. While that guide is intended for players going for a perfect score, that's not necessary for an S rank; you'll get it as long as you clear the game with at least 130,000,000G. Keep in mind that obtaining this much (and, by extension, obtaining an S rank) is only possible in the Hidden Mansion.